# Azure Application Gateway - ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE when creating a Path-based routing rule using HTTPS listener

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I have an Azure Application Gateway and trying to set up a Path-based routing with SSL.

Backend pool target servers are App Services, which are allowed to accept both HTTP and HTTPS traffic.

## Configuration in details

### **Backend pools**

- Pool1 -> Contains one App Service
- Pool2 -> Contains one App Service

### **Backend settings**

- Backend protocol -> HTTPS
- Used the well known CA certificate option
- Host name override -> Pick host name from backend target (for App Services to be accessible)

### **Frontend IP configuration**

- One public IP address

### **Routing Rule**

- Listener - HTTP_Listener
- Backend targets
- Path based rules
- Path: "/path1/*" -> Pool1
- Path: "/path2/*" -> Pool2

Then I have the HTTP listener, it works fine and I can access the domain: subdomain.domain.com

Routes are also working fine:

- http://subdomain.domain.com/path1/
- http://subdomain.domain.com/path2/

### And after this stage I cannot configure to access the domain by HTTPS.

## HTTPS Listener configuration

- Protocol: HTTPS
- Certificate: Self-signed certificate
- Listener type: Multi site -> Host names: "*.domain.com"

---

## The error

When I swith the listener in routing rule from HTTP to HTTPS, I receive an error in web-browser:

'subdomain.domain.com' didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

---

P.S. Creating the self-signed certificate in PowerShell

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate  -certstorelocation cert:\localmachine\my  -dnsname subdomain.domain.name
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "12345" -Force -AsPlainText
Export-PfxCertificate -cert cert:\localMachine\my\0000000000 -FilePath c:\cert.pfx -Password $pwd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I just restarted the network interface and it worked. As simple as that.